# Sign into different third party app accounts

Tags: ios, dropbox, authentication, third-party

I'd like to be able to sign into different third party apps with separate accounts. Is there a way to force iOS to open a web view instead of switching to the app for sign in? For example, I currently have an app that I want to use to sign in to Dropbox. When I click sign in, it redirects to my Dropbox app, which is already signed in, but I want to use a different Dropbox account for that app. How can I make it open a web view so I can sign into a different Dropbox account directly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the SDK that app developers are including from Dropbox. You will have to contact the app developer for an alternative or for a modification of this behavior.